# Web socket Swift crash link

Tags: swift, web-services, url, websocket

I have link for web soket. I checked it on https://www.websocket.org and it connected. [image]However when I start to create URL object

```
if let url = URL(string: "wss://ios-devchallenge-11.tk/write?id={id}") {

        socket = WebSocket(url: url, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])



        socket?.delegate = self
        socket?.connect()

    }
```

I got error. What do I wrong?

Comment: I can't unwrap. Object of URL(..) is not created and compiler can't enter inside if

Comment: I have no experience in web sockets but I think that `id={id}` is not correct...

Comment: Thank you thats works! If you want you can post your answer, I confirm it

Answer (score 1):

I turn out I set wrong url. I change code as below (removed {})

```
if let url = URL(string: "wss://ios-devchallenge-11.tk/write?id=id") {

    socket = WebSocket(url: url, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])



    socket?.delegate = self
    socket?.connect()

}
```